# App-specific bluetooth connection

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing an authentication layer for a hardware device communicating with an android app over Bluetooth. I want to ensure that the device only communicates with our app. Is there any way to prevent a user from connecting to the device with our app, and then open another app and continue communicating with the device using the existing connection? There are ways to solve this with cryptography but as this might be expensive I'm looking for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If security is your main concern perform the connection using secure BT
socket, which can be created via direct call to createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord
(most modern devices) or call by reflection to "createRfcommSocket" (some old devices).

[BTWiz](https://github.com/giladHaimov/BTWiz) does a good job in hiding away such complexities from you, as well as supporting async Bluetooth IO.

This will give you a 'basic' level of security.

I assume you want more, and the only way to obtain this will be by performing
some level of applicative authentication. If does not have to be complex, the mere
passing of a simple passphrase from side to side will give you a higher level of
authentication than most BT implementations I met.

Gilad Haimov

Android Developer

www.mobileedge.co.il